# ImageMap display in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have building image with seating positions, I have to display selected location of image on button click. example If user select seat num 120 I have to locate seat num 120 and highlight the seat num. Image is very big 2000x1500 size so I have to show the image with selected position ,like in google map it display searching location..

Please let me know how to achive this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way would be to use the "area" tag of HTML (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)
Then you would be able to link every seat to a detail page with information about it.
This will not solve your highlight problem though.
Do you have to stick to the image?